# CPPUnit access defines in c files

Tags: c, unit-testing, cppunit

I am doing some unit test on c code using CPPUnit.

In the code to test there are some defines in c files and not in the h files. So they are not accessable from other places in the code. Many of the defines are used to set the size of arrays.

When I do the unit tests I would like to make them so dynamical as possible meaning that they will still work when the defines are changed before the final release. I've made some loops and stuff to go through the functions using the arrays, so that I test as many times as there are entries in an array etc. But until now I use a copy of the define in my unit test code. So if the defines are changed in the code to test, then they are not changed in the unit test code.

So my main question is, if there is some trick to use just for the unit testing purpose to somehow making the defines global or anything without changing the original source code just to fit the use of unit testing. Maybe a compiler setting? (I am using visual studio 2008).

Comment: What about simply including the C file? `#include "myfile.c"` does that work?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure about VS but in Clang and GCC you can use the `-D<define-name>=<value>` compiler flags.

Comment: Why not write the code properly and put the defines where they belong, in header files?

Comment: @Radek -D won't override `#define` statements in the code.

Comment: @Jim Balter nothing is said about overriding them.

Comment: @Radek Read the question and think about it.

Comment: It actually works with including the c file. Haven't thought about that. So simple. Thanks :o) It just destroys the way I set up the rest of my test suite. But think I will set up the test for this only in their own special project then.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot make a `#define` in a .c file "global" so that it applies to other C files, any more than you can make a static function global without changing the source. The way to do this is to change the source to put those `#define`s where they belong, in header files that define interfaces.

=== edit ===

credit to Radek S for the idea of `#include`ing the .c file. This has limited applicability, but should work for unit tests of functions in that one file, provided that the the original file is not compiled when creating the test executable.